# Finding the max or min of values in local sets of rows of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So for example, I have a dataframe like this

```
   Value   Placement
0    12      high
1    15      high
2    18      high
3    14      high
4    4       low
5    5       low
6    9       high
7    11      high
8    2       low
9    1       low
10   3       low
11   2       low
```

I want to create a second dataframe that contains the the highest value in the "Value" column for each set of consecutive rows with "high" placement, and the lowest value in the "Value" column for each set of consecutive rows with "low" placement. So something like

```
   Value   Placement
0    18      high
1    4       low
2    11      high
3    1       low
```

I also don't want to change the order of the rows, as the order of the "highs" and "lows" is critical to the functionality of the project.

I could just iterate through the original dataframe and keep track of the the numbers in "Value" until a change in "Placement" is detected, but I've heard dataframe iteration is very slow and should be avoided if possible. Is there some way to do this without iteration? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by consecutive values, swap the sign for Placement that match "low", and get the [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) per group, then keep the selected rows with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
# group consecutive rows
group = df['Placement'].ne(df['Placement'].shift()).cumsum()

# invert the low values, get idxmax per group
keep = (df['Value']
        .mul(df['Placement'].map({'low': -1, 'high': 1}))
        .groupby(group, sort=False).idxmax()
        )

out = df.loc[keep]
```

If efficiency is a concern, and since `groupby` is based on a python loop, another approach (that is potentially faster for many groups) would be to stable-sort the rows by value and group (using [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html)) and keep the highest (after sign swap for "low") using [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
group = df['Placement'].ne(df['Placement'].shift()).cumsum()
s = df['Value'].mul(df['Placement'].map({'low': -1, 'high': 1}))

keep = (group
        .iloc[np.lexsort([s, group])]
        .drop_duplicates(keep='last')
        .index
        )

out = df.loc[keep]
```

*Note that despite the sorting step, this strategy will maintain the relative original order of the rows.*

Output:

```
   Value Placement
2     18      high
4      4       low
7     11      high
9      1       low
```

Comparison of timing:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
out = df.loc[
    df.groupby((df["Placement"] != df["Placement"].shift()).cumsum()).apply(
        lambda g: g["Value"].idxmax()
        if g["Placement"].iat[0] == "high"
        else g["Value"].idxmin()
    )
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   Value Placement
2     18      high
4      4       low
7     11      high
9      1       low
```

Comment: Will just have to do `out= out.reset_index(drop=True)` to match the output exactly

Answer (score 2):

```py
def sel(g):
    v = g['Value']
    return g.iloc[v.argmax() if g['Placement'].iloc[0] == 'high' else v.argmin()]

grp = (df != df.shift())['Placement'].cumsum()
>>> df.groupby(grp, as_index=False, sort=False).apply(sel)
   Value Placement
0     18      high
1      4       low
2     11      high
3      1       low
```

Comment: Isn't it more or less the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77567683)? ;)

Comment: subtle differences... arg instead of idx (works in case of index with duplicates); same index as OP; concise (b ut less efficient) calculation of `grp`.

Comment: Actually, not exactly since slicing is done by the groupby, but I'd expect it to make it slower.

Comment: I got `4.12 ms ± 286 µs` vs `3.16 ms ± 179 µs` using OPs example, I I'll try to test on a larger input.

Comment: yes, my bad, I forgot to add the `grp = ` in the timeit (facepalm). I contend that using `argmax` vs `idxmax` is safer, if the index is not a simple `RangeIndex`. And, in that case, we can't just use that to slice the whole `df` since that is relative to each group. I was really going for correctness and concision of code. For speed, I would use `numpy` (as you do).

Comment: Fair enough in case of a duplicated index. Regarding the timings, this got me intrigued so I performed a full benchmark (see my answer). Your alternative grouper is in fact not changing much, but the slicing in the `apply` is reproducibly less efficient.

Comment: Nice! Love `perfplot`.